# Creating own node modules to export and import via babel transpiler

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

My target is doing something like this in another project

```
import { FuncA, FuncB, FuncC } from @myorg/hellow
```

---

I am creating my own node module for internal issue and I have defined the folder structure of hellow as follows:

```
hellow
 ┣ dist(ES5 of src)
 ┣ src
 ┃ ┣ Fileone
 ┃ ┃ ┗ Fileone.js
 ┃ ┃ Filetwo
 ┃ ┃ ┗ Filetwo.js
 ┃ ┗ index.js
 ┣ .babelrc
 ┣ .gitignore
 ┣ .npmignore
 ┣ index.js
 ┣ package-lock.json
 ┗ package.json
```

The **index.js** looks like this:

```
module.exports = require('./dist');
```

The **package.json** with some fields omitted looks like this:

```
"main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "npx babel src --out-dir dist"
    },
    "license": "MIT",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.16.0",
        "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.4",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.13",
        "create-index": "^2.6.0"
    },
```

and the **.babelrc** file looks like this:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

---

The **index.js in the src folder** acts as an aggregator for the exported functions in Fileone.js, Filetwo.js, and so it looks like this:

```
export { FuncA, FuncB } from './Fileone/Fileone.js';
export { FuncC } from './Filetwo/Filetwo.js';
```

And then file **Fileone.js** (and similarly Filetwo.js) has some code like:

```
const FuncA = ...
const FuncB = ...
...
export { FuncA, FuncB }
```

---

After setting the package like so I do the following to publish to npm

```
npm run build
npm publish
cd ../project-directory
npm update @myorg/hellow
npm run dev
```

The error I am getting has something to do with missing syntax:

"Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports."

```
.next\server\pages\_document.js (12:4) @ Object.ctx.renderPage

  10 |          // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
  11 |          ctx.renderPage = () =>
> 12 |              originalRenderPage({
     |          ^
  13 |                  enhanceApp: App => props =>
  14 |                      sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
  15 |              });
```

But I browsed a lot and can't figure out where I'm going wrong. I am guessing it has something to do with the transpilation into ES5?

---

**Edit:** I have since removed the **root index.js** file and modified **package.json** such that the entry is like this:

```
~~"main": "index.js"~~
"main": "dist/index.js"
```

Same error still.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that in the above step when I mentioned:

---

The **index.js in the src folder** acts as an aggregator for the exported functions in Fileone.js, Filetwo.js, and so it looks like this:

```
export { FuncA, FuncB } from './Fileone/Fileone.js';
export { FuncC } from './Filetwo/Filetwo.js';
```

---

I needed to instead use:

```
export { FuncA, FuncB } from './Fileone/Fileone';
export { FuncC } from './Filetwo/Filetwo';
```

without the .js extensions. Seems to be working now.